# How do I secure my network with an open wifi?

Tags: wifi

I have a business with an open Wifi router for my customers, I was wondering if I put the wifi router on a different subnet would help protect my wired network?

Answer (score 2):

If the subnet is logically separated from your business network using a firewall, then it will make your network more secure.

If it's just a separate IP subnet with full access into your business network, then it will no really make things any more secure.

This question has more details: [Sharing wifi at a business - Bad Policy?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6542/sharing-wifi-at-a-business-bad-policy)

Comment: Some Wifi nodes may provide an "isolated" Guest network, but I probably wouldn't trust one of those to keep my network secure, I'd use a separate node in a separate firewalled network (or even outside of my network entirely, on the "WAN" side of my firewall) to provide an open guest network. This is just a personal opinion so I've left it as a comment rather than part of my answer.

Comment: These are very good suggestions, but what if it's just a cable modem hooked up with a wifi router?  It seems like just the Guest network maybe the only solution for that setup.  My business has 10 employees and only the 3 people use computers.

Comment: It depends on your tolerance for risk -- using your Wifi node's built-in Guest network is likely better than doing nothing at all, but if it were me, I'd want a separate Wifi node for the guest users that's isolated from my business network with a separate firewall. Of course, that's easy for me to say since I wouldn't have to hire anyone to configure it, so you may value the simplicity of not having additional hardware to purchase and configure.